# How to extract weights of the best ANN resulting from GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

After running the hyperparameter tuning with GridSearchCV with the code as below:

```
## Tuning the ANN
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
def build_regressor(hidden_nodes, hidden_layers, optimizer):
  regressor = Sequential()
  regressor.add(Dense(units = hidden_nodes, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 7))
  for layer_size in range(hidden_layers):
      regressor.add(Dense(hidden_nodes, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
  regressor.add(Dense(units = 1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'linear'))
  regressor.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'mse', metrics = ['mse'])
  return regressor
regressor = KerasRegressor(build_fn = build_regressor, epochs = 100)

# Create a dictionary of tuning parameters
parameters = {'hidden_nodes': list(range(2,101)), 'hidden_layers': [1,2,3], 'batch_size': [25,32], 'optimizer' : ['adam', 'nadam','RMSprop', 'adamax']}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = regressor, param_grid = parameters, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error', cv = 10, n_jobs = 4)
grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
best_parameters = grid_search.best_params_
best_score = grid_search.best_score_
best_model = grid_search.best_estimator_
```

Do we have any way to extract the weights of the best model from GridSearchCV?

Thank you so much in advance,

Comment: Do you mean to save the model weights to a file?

Comment: @yudhiesh Yes, I want to save the best model's weights into a '.csv' file to estimate the Garson's algorithm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you want the model weights saved in a `csv` file you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np

weight = best_model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
np.savetxt('weight.csv' , weight , fmt='%s', delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I tried your code but I got this error message `'KerasRegressor' object has no attribute 'get_weights'`.

Comment: @HoangMaiTrinh Hi I have updated the answer

Comment: @judhiesh Unfortunately, I still have an error of `AttributeError: 'KerasRegressor' object has no attribute 'layers'`

Comment: @HoangMaiTrinh could you run `dir(best_model)` and add the result?

Comment: @judhiesh  `['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__slotnames__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 'build_fn',
 'check_params',
 'filter_sk_params',
 'fit',
 'get_params',
 'model',
 'predict',
 'score',
 'set_params',
 'sk_params']`

Comment: @judhiesh Is it what you meant?